# Is there a way to combine, following certain criteria, a max of 3 multidimensional array's with OOP PHP objects into one array?

Tags: php, sorting, oop, object, multidimensional-array

**Edited :**
Shorter more generic version :

Im looking for an algorithm in PHP to combine max 3 multidimensional object arrays into one multidimensional object array.

But there are some specific things I need, so a simple array_merge is not enough.

- If there are duplicates the ranking must be adjusted, so this result
  item needs to go up in the array.
- For the other results : it
  needs to weave the results of the same height into each other rather
  than just pasting the results under each other like an array_merge
  would do.
- Also I need to keep into account that later the
  application might be expanded with ratings for results so that the ranking might also be subjective to adaptation bases on ratings.

---

```
Array1(
Object A
”Title” => ”A”
”Rank” => 0

Object B
”Title” => ”B”
”Rank” => 1

Object C
”Title” => ”C”
”Rank” => 2

Object S
”Title” =>” S”
”Rank” => 2
)
```

--

```
Array 2 (
Object X
”Title” => X
”Rank” => 0

Object Z
”Title” => ”Z”
”Rank” => 1

Object C
”Title” =>” C”
”Rank” => 2
)
```

--

```
Array3(
Object Z
”Title” => ”Z”
”Rank” => 0

Object A
”Title” => ”A”
”Rank” => 1

Object C
”Title” => ”C”
”Rank” => 2
)
```

--
Result should be :

```
combinedArray(
Object C // is found by all tree
”Title” => ”C”
”Rank” => 2

Object A // is found in 2
”Title” => ”A”
”Rank” => 0

Object Z // is found in 2
”Title” => ”Z”
”Rank” => 0

Object X
”Title” => X
”Rank” => 0

Object B
”Title” => ”B”
”Rank” => 1

Object S
”Title” =>” S”
”Rank” => 2
)
```

__

Preferred language of answer is PHP.

Thank you in advance for your help and taking the time to read all of this!

Comment: IMHO the problem with this as a question here is that there is way to much detail for most people to want to wade through it.  You may struggle to get answers just because of this.

Comment: Thank you i'm a total newb to posting here... 
Maybe you could be so kind to provide suggestions how i can shorten the question, please? 
I was Affraid without all the info it might not be clear enough what I'm asking....

Comment: @NigelRen I tried to make the question shorter and more generic, is this better?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is how I would tackle it, which is just a loop and a usort at the end to set the order according to newRank. Also I'm assuming a duplicate is just the url. Link to output is here: http://codepad.org/ClubESQ6

```
<?php

//google
$res1 = array();
$res1[0] = array('id'=>null, 'title'=>'Owl - Wikipedia', 'urlLink'=>'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Owl', 'currentRank'=>0, 'newRank'=>null);
$res1[1] = array('id'=>null, 'title'=>'Owl (Marvel Comics) - Wikipedia', 'urlLink'=>'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Owl_(Marvel_Comics)', 'currentRank'=>1, 'newRank'=>null);
$res1[2] = array('id'=>null, 'title'=>'Owl Pharaoh - Wikipedia', 'urlLink'=>'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Owl_Pharaoh', 'currentRank'=>2, 'newRank'=>null);
$res1[3] = array('id'=>null, 'title'=>'Owl City - Wikipedia', 'urlLink'=>'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Owl_City', 'currentRank'=>3, 'newRank'=>null);
$res1[4] = array('id'=>null, 'title'=>'Owl (Nguyen Hung Cuong) | Happy Folding', 'urlLink'=>'https://www.happyfolding.com/gallery-nguyen-owl', 'currentRank'=>1, 'newRank'=>null);

//bing
$res2 = array();
$res2[0] = array('id'=>null, 'title'=>'OWL/TV - Wikipedia', 'urlLink'=>'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OWL/TV', 'currentRank'=>0, 'newRank'=>null);
$res2[1] = array('id'=>null, 'title'=>'Owl (Nguyen Hung Cuong) | Happy Folding', 'urlLink'=>'https://www.happyfolding.com/gallery-nguyen-owl', 'currentRank'=>1, 'newRank'=>null);
$res2[2] = array('id'=>null, 'title'=>'Owl Pharaoh - Wikipedia', 'urlLink'=>'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Owl_Pharaoh', 'currentRank'=>2, 'newRank'=>null);
$res2[3] = array('id'=>null, 'title'=>'Owl "Nightwatch" (Kay Kraschewski a.k.a. "Akugami ...', 'urlLink'=>'https://www.happyfolding.com/instructions-kraschewski-nightwatch', 'currentRank'=>3, 'newRank'=>null);
$res2[4] = array('id'=>null, 'title'=>'Owl - Wikipedia', 'urlLink'=>'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Owl', 'currentRank'=>0, 'newRank'=>null);

//duckduckgo
$res3 = array();
$res3[0] = array('id'=>null, 'title'=>'OWL // Purdue Writing Lab', 'urlLink'=>'https://owl.purdue.edu', 'currentRank'=>0, 'newRank'=>null);
$res3[1] = array('id'=>null, 'title'=>'Owl - Wikipedia', 'urlLink'=>'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Owl', 'currentRank'=>1, 'newRank'=>null);
$res3[2] = array('id'=>null, 'title'=>'Owl | bird | Britannica.com', 'urlLink'=>'https://www.britannica.com/animal/owl', 'currentRank'=>2, 'newRank'=>null);
$res3[3] = array('id'=>null, 'title'=>'The Owl Pages - Information about Owls', 'urlLink'=>'https://www.owlpages.com/owls/', 'currentRank'=>3, 'newRank'=>null);


$results = mergeResults($res1, $res2, $res3);

echo '<pre>', print_r($results, true), '</pre>';


function mergeResults() {
    $results = array(); //array for our final resulsts
    $numargs = func_num_args();
    $arg_list = func_get_args();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $numargs; $i++) {
        $resultSet = $arg_list[$i];
        foreach($resultSet as $rs) {
            //is dupe, decrement rank
            if (isset($results[$rs['urlLink']])) {
                $currentRank = $results[$rs['urlLink']]['newRank'];
                $newRank = $currentRank - 1;
                $results[$rs['urlLink']]['newRank'] = $newRank;
            } else {
                $rs['newRank']  = $rs['currentRank'];
                $results[$rs['urlLink']] = $rs; 
            }
        }
    }

    usort($results, "sortByRank");

    return $results;
}

function sortByRank($a, $b) {
    if($a["newRank"] == $b["newRank"]) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a["newRank"] < $b["newRank"]) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @cOle2!

I needed to fiddle abit with it, but got it to work!

I needed and extra indentation in the foreach because it was trying to find urlLink in a to high level.
And because I'm working with classes I needed to expand the usort request with the class to, which was something new for me so took me abit longer to find the answer for... 
usort($this->results, array($this, "sortByRank"));

Thank you!